# Why mocking functions with volatile arguments is not compiling for GMock 1.8.0

Tags: c++, volatile, googlemock

Considering this snippet

```
MOCK_METHOD1(foo, int(volatile int*));
```

This piece of code was compiling fine with GMock 1.7.0 but when i updated to GMock 1.8.0 it's throwing an error

```
../gmock/fused-src/gtest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:467:6: error: reinterpret_cast from type 'volatile int*' to type 'const void*' casts away qualifiers
*os << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(p);
^
```

It's obvious that it's not compiling because `reinterpret_cast` is , by definition, not able to remove cv-qualifiers.

I need to mention also that i'm using c++98 so `remove_volatile` ,unfortunately, can't be used.

Also, some of the functions' arguments have the volatile specifier by default due to their direct interaction with memory in an embedded device.

Is there a way to get rid of this issue ?

is it actually a missing feature in Gmock ?

Comment: I know zip about Gmock, but regarding your C++98 comment: `remove_volatile` is trivial to implement using C++98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open proposal](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/546) to extend GMock to provide support you need:

> Currently gmock don't have macros for mocking volatile and const
>   volatile  methods.  There are several options to solve this:
>
> 1. provide
>
>    MOCK_VOLATILE_METHOD0   MOCK_VOLATILE_METHOD0_T
>      MOCK_VOLATILE_METHOD0_WITH_CALLTYPE
>      MOCK_VOLATILE_METHOD0_T_WITH_CALLTYPE
>
> and friends as needed.
>
> 2. expose a variation of GMOCK_METHOD0_ to let the user write
>
>    GMOCK_METHOD0(volatile, , Foo, int());   GMOCK_METHOD0_T(const
>      volatile, , Bar, int());

Before that have been accepted and implemented - you might workaround such kind of problems by calling mocked function from "real" one:

```
virtual void foo(volatile int* param) { mockedFoo(const_cast<int*>(param)); }
MOCK_METHOD1(mockedFoo, int(int*));
```